# C++ initialization list for class with "min" member

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, initialization

I have seen a class where someone named member variables `min` and `max`

```
class A
{
public:
 A();
 ~A();
 bool min;
 bool max;
 ...
};
```

with a constructor

```
A::A()
{
  min=false;
  max=true;
  ...
}
```

I have tried to rewrite it with usage of an initialization list:

```
A::A():min(false), max(true){}
```

but I have received an warning + error

```
warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'min'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

because `min` macro is defined in `WinDef.h`

Is it possible to use initialization list in this situation without renaming of the member variables?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy No: `error C2059: syntax error : 'this'`

Comment: Look up NOMINMAX

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: In C++ it would be `this->` but that's still part of an expression, and the initializer list contains members not epxressions.

Comment: I'd spell the member names out as `minimum` and `maximum` and avoid this mess, but that's just me.

Comment: This is a great example of why macros should generally be avoided as they just stomp all over everything regardless of context.

Comment: Hey, it's Windows, so call them `m_Min` and `m_Max` :-)

Comment: Wait until you start using standard algorithms like `min` and `max`. Best is to avoid those windows headers as much as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have VS2013 or another modern compiler:

```
A():min {false}, max {true} { }
```

avoids the problem because `min(a,b)` is a function-style macro and `{`  can't start its argument list.

This is specific to initializer lists, so I've reopened the question. The "duplicate" suggested addresses macro use in expression context, which is fundamentally different - you can use `(min)` there.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation you have several options.

1. Use brace initialisation as suggested by @MSalters
2. Define `NOMINMAX` before you include the windows header files to avoid the `min` and `max` macros from being defined. This will depend on how big your code is and how much control you have over it.
3. Just `#undef` the macros. Only recommend in a source file.
4. Use MSVC pre-processor directives to save, undef then restore the macros. Like so...

   ```
   #pragma push_macro("min")
   #undef min
   /* use min here */
   #pragma pop_macro("min")
   ```

Comment: The downside to defining `NOMINMAX` is that other sources might be expecting `min` and `max` to exist.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Yes exactly, the same is true for using `#undef`, you have to be careful where you put that and what code could potentially be compiled after.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: That might be solved by a further `using std::min; using std::max`. It's quite uncommon for code to depend on `min` and `max` being macro's.